How do I get more information when Error.cshtml is called?
I created a Blazor Interactive Server app and it has the files Error.cshtml and Error.cshtml.cs. I do not know why/when they are called. I added logging in:
public void OnGet()
{
    RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
    _logger.LogError($"HttpContext ERROR - RequestId: {RequestId}");
}

And I just found this in the logs. A bunch of times (never logged before).
So, how do I figure out what is wrong from this? All I have is:
Error 18:43:37.213 [WN0XSDWK0000F5]-[] LouisHowe.web.Pages.ErrorModel - HttpContext ERROR - RequestId: 00-a75cd8fc9d26802420f3012acbf5b105-987aeef00b7c7b96-00
Error 18:45:14.269 [wn0xsdwk0000AC]-[] LouisHowe.web.Pages.ErrorModel - HttpContext ERROR - RequestId: 00-4ed40d7b04335ed2bf1a6e9dc1f22811-74c6ca9a64a318cb-00
Error 18:45:14.124 [WN0XSDWK0000F5]-[] LouisHowe.web.Pages.ErrorModel - HttpContext ERROR - RequestId: 00-ff85c8e5e8b8182b4b89c761f0e66c3c-c5d60949ecac5375-00

and I have no idea what to go look for.
